# How do I print amount total on classic report in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex

I have a classic report in Oracle Apex. I want to print the total of amount column in report. How can I do that? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Go to column's properties, scroll down to "Advanced" section and turn the **Compute sum** property ON.

Comment: this will only show in report but not in the print section.